# LEFT JOIN by closer value condition

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have this query

```
SELECT
    loc.proceso,
    loc.codigo_municipio,
    loc.codigo_concejo,
    loc.concejo,
    (CASE
        WHEN loc.poblacion IS NOT NULL THEN loc.poblacion
        ELSE pob.valor
    END) AS poblacion
FROM develop.031401_elecciones_dimension_localizacion_electoral AS loc
LEFT JOIN develop.031401_elecciones_dimension_proceso_electoral AS proc
ON loc.proceso = proc.proceso
LEFT JOIN develop.020101_t05 AS pob
ON loc.codigo_municipio = CAST(pob.cmun AS INT) AND pob.year = proc.anno_eleccion
```

In the second `LEFT JOIN`, I would like to change the second condition `pob.year = proc.anno_eleccion` so that it does not only search for the exact year when joining. Instead, I would like to get the closer year stored in my `pob` table. For example, the first year stored in `pob` is `2003`, so I want all the entries in `loc` whose year is lower than `2003` to be matched with that value when performing the join. Also at the inverse, the last year stored in `pob` is `2020`, so I want those entries in `loc` whose year is `2021` (or even greater), to be matched with the `2020` row from my `pob` table. When the exact year is contained in `pob` table, it should be used for the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. If you want the nearest year to NOW**

I don't think of a direct join but you can try this one by using `ROW_NUMBER()` function to sort data by year and pick the first result to join:
(`WHERE rn = 1` picks the first index, so it prevents any duplicate)

```
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT T.* FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pob.cmun ORDER BY pob.year DESC) AS rn,
   *
FROM develop.020101_t05) AS T
WHERE rn = 1) AS pob
ON loc.codigo_municipio = CAST(pob.cmun AS INT) AND pob.year = proc.anno_eleccion
```

**2. If you want the nearest year to your data**

Even it's not best practice, you can join your data using comparison operators on join condition. Then, take the difference between two years, sort the difference ascending and pick the first result using `ROW_NUMBER()` function. See example:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Id ORDER BY a.Year - b.Year) AS RowNumber,
       a.Id,
       a.Year,
       b.Year,
       a.Year - b.Year AS YearDiff
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.Id = b.Id AND a.Year >= b.Year) AS T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: But if I always pick the last year how would I join data from other years which are not the most recent one?

Comment: If that's what you want, you can use comparison operators such as `proc.anno_eleccion <= pob.year` or vice versa. So, you will join the data of all years of `proc` less than `pob.year`. But you will probably encounter a duplication issue (1 to many relationship), so please be aware of that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using the `<=` but I found the duplication issue you mentioned. That was why I was asking for a solution which allowed me to use that operator keeping the original number of entries @highlytrainedbadger

Comment: On your duplicated data; take the difference between `pob.year` and `loc.year` for each row, then use `GROUP BY` and `MIN()` for those differences on whatever column you use as UID. Finally, you can select the ids with the least difference. Another option is to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY year_difference) AS row_num` and filter `row_num = 1` from outside of the query.

Comment: Please check out the edited answer for the second option.